# Is it possible to make command prompt in Java?

Tags: java

I would just like to know whether it is possible to make a command prompt in Java.
My friend asked to make it, I wanted to know if it was possible or not. If it is possible, can someone suggest me some api or something? Thank you.

EDIT: I want to make it similar to windows command prompt

EDIT 2: I would like to make a SWING GUI application and put a command prompt inside of it.

Comment: Do you mean you want to implement your own console in java?

Comment: It is possible. However, please elaborate. Do you mean command prompt similar to cmd.exe in windows?

Comment: that clarifies things...

Comment: Thanks for editing. Do you want your program to **create** a window (Swing GUI) and put your command prompt inside? Or maybe you want to use `System.in` / `System.out`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can run commands in Java using the Process API. You can also **get** the output and **write** input to the runned process. For more info, see [this tutorial](http://www.devdaily.com/java/edu/pj/pj010016).

But if you want to make a **terminal emulator** (such as those in Linux) in Java,
I recommend having a look at [JCTerm](http://www.jcraft.com/jcterm/) or [JTA](http://javassh.org/space/start).

Answer (score 7):

Yes. Use the [Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) API.

Answer (score 2):

You must be careful how you start it.

If you start your program with java.exe then the console (input/output) is shown. With `System.out.println("mymessage");` you can print (output) text to the console. With `System.in` you can read from the console. This delegates to the `java.io.Console` class (available throug `System.console()`).

If you start your program with javaw.exe, then you don't see the console. You must then create your own screen to allow input/output. This is the default on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Java can do console I/O and it can launch processes, so yes, it's possible.  You'd use methods of `System.in` and `System.out` to display a prompt and read commands, and a [ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to execute programs.

Answer (score 0):

Check the class `java.lang.Runtime`. It provides a couple of `exec()` methods.

Answer (score 0):

yes it's possible in java

your have to do some research on Java.lang & IO