# How to embed a windows program inside java component

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jframe

I have done a little research online with no luck, and I cant seem to see a question on SO similar to this.

I wanted to know if its possible to place a windows program to fit inside a jFrame or jWindow. The particular example I had in mind was if I were to create a jFrame, can I spawn a windows program to open (i.e. cmd.exe) and embed that window within my jFrame somewhere. Hopefully the following image depicts what Im trying to acheive.

[image]

Comment: Are you trying to create a program that is like a command prompt? Or do you want to have a button that the user clicks and it runs a windows program?

Comment: Ideally, I would have a button or two at the top, and depending on which was clicked, the lower half of the window would spawn a program and embed it within the window. i.e. button1 clicked would result in a cmd window showing inside the frame, button2 would result in a cygwin window, or a notepad window being shown and so on.

Comment: This may be what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804769/is-it-possible-to-make-command-prompt-in-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been asked before several times on this site, and always, as far as I can recall the answer is the same: while yes this is theoretically feasible, it is extraordinarily difficult to implement, especially since Java Swing uses light weight components that are not created by the OS, but created by the Swing itself. You would be better off using a language that allows you to get tighter with the operating system such as C# if Windows or C/C++ with Windows and most everything else.

So my final answer: this is not practical with Java Swing GUI's.

---

**Edit**
Note that if all you want to do is to stream output from the command line, this can be done by displaying it in a JTextField or JEditPane or JTextPane. There is no need to embed an OS window into the GUI for this.

Comment: Thanks, I was beginning to think that this might be the case.

Comment: I have, unfortunately that is not what I was looking for. In reality I wanted a sort of window tiling feature, where I could show say a cmd prompt, a notepad window and so on and then tile them in different layouts next to each other.

Comment: @Husman: if this is for the Windows platform, how about looking into using C#? If you know Java, you should quickly pick up on C# as the syntax is similar.