# How can I embed microsoft word in java Form?

Tags: java, ms-word

I want to read a word document with the help of microsoft word but that would be limited to my java form . The document will be opened in java form with the help of microsoft word .

Like the following picture , I want to develop something : 
 [image]

User can edit the doc according to their need . But when they want to save the document , the document will be saved in a remote machine .

I can open the word document with the help of microsoft word by the following code :

```
try {
            /* if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported()) {
                  Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("E:\\finger.docx"));
             }*/
            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime()
                .exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler E:\\finger.docx");
             p.waitFor(); 
            System.out.println("Done.");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
              ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(JavaFromWord.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

But I do not know how can I embed the word viewer in JForm . Please help me .

Comment: Not (realistically) doable. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23225885/how-to-embed-a-windows-program-inside-java-component

Comment: Is this a [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info)?

Comment: @Gowtham It is definitely an XY problem.

Comment: I suspect you will eventually want something more like this http://www.docx4java.org/trac/docx4j

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have succeeded to do this job . The following code helps me a lot to do it .

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.SWTError;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.KeyListener;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionAdapter;
import org.eclipse.swt.events.SelectionEvent;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OLE;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleClientSite;
import org.eclipse.swt.ole.win32.OleFrame;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Event;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.FileDialog;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Listener;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Menu;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.MenuItem;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

import com.connect.DBConnectionHandler;

public class SWTMenuExample {
    static OleClientSite clientSite;
    static OleFrame frame;
    static File file;
    static Shell shell;
    static KeyListener keyListener;
    static Display display;

    public static void main(final String[] args) {
        display = new Display();
        shell = new Shell(display);

        shell.setSize(800, 600);
        shell.setText("Word Example");
        shell.setLayout(new FillLayout());

        try {
            frame = new OleFrame(shell, SWT.NONE);
            // esto abre un documento existente
            // clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, new
            // File("Doc1.doc"));
            // esto abre un documento en blanco
            // clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Word.Document");
            addFileMenu(frame);
            System.out.println(" I am in run method ");
        } catch (final SWTError e) {
            System.out.println("Unable to open activeX control");
            display.dispose();
            return;
        }

        keyListener = new KeyListener() {

            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {

            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent paramKeyEvent) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                if (((paramKeyEvent.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL)
                        && (paramKeyEvent.keyCode == 's')) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                            "ctrl+s is pressed down initial ",
                            "Warning Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    if (file != null) {
                        clientSite.save(file, true);
                        fileSave();
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,
                                "ctrl+s is pressed down", "Warning Message",
                                JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    } else
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File is null",
                                "Warning Message", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                }

            }
        };

        display.addFilter(SWT.KeyDown, new Listener() {

            public void handleEvent(Event e) {
                if (((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL)
                        && (e.keyCode == 's')) {
                    System.out.println("From Display I am the Key down !!"
                            + e.keyCode);
                }
            }
        });

        final Color green = display.getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_GREEN);
        final Color orig = shell.getBackground();

        shell.addKeyListener(new KeyListener() {
            public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
                if (((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL)
                        && (e.keyCode == 's')) {
                    shell.setBackground(orig);
                    System.out.println("Key up !!");
                }
            }

            public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                if (((e.stateMask & SWT.CTRL) == SWT.CTRL)
                        && (e.keyCode == 's')) {
                    shell.setBackground(green);
                    System.out.println("Key down !!");
                }
            }
        });

        shell.open();
        while (!shell.isDisposed()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch()) {
                display.sleep();
            }
        }
        display.dispose();
    }

    static void addFileMenu(OleFrame frame) {
        final Shell shell = frame.getShell();
        Menu menuBar = shell.getMenuBar();
        if (menuBar == null) {
            menuBar = new Menu(shell, SWT.BAR);
            shell.setMenuBar(menuBar);
        }
        MenuItem fileMenu = new MenuItem(menuBar, SWT.CASCADE);
        fileMenu.setText("&File");
        Menu menuFile = new Menu(fileMenu);
        fileMenu.setMenu(menuFile);
        frame.setFileMenus(new MenuItem[] { fileMenu });

        MenuItem menuFileCreate = new MenuItem(menuFile, SWT.CASCADE);
        menuFileCreate.setText("Create File");
        menuFileCreate.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                fileCreate();
            }
        });

        MenuItem menuFileOpen = new MenuItem(menuFile, SWT.CASCADE);
        menuFileOpen.setText("Open File");
        menuFileOpen.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                fileOpen();
            }
        });

        MenuItem menuFileSave = new MenuItem(menuFile, SWT.CASCADE);
        menuFileSave.setText("Save File");
        menuFileSave.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                if (file != null) {
                    clientSite.save(file, true);
                    fileSave();
                }
            }
        });

        MenuItem menuFileClose = new MenuItem(menuFile, SWT.CASCADE);
        menuFileClose.setText("Close File");
        menuFileClose.addSelectionListener(new SelectionAdapter() {
            public void widgetSelected(SelectionEvent e) {
                if (clientSite != null) {
                    clientSite.dispose();
                    file = null;
                }
            }
        });
    }

    static void fileCreate() {
        if (clientSite != null)
            clientSite.dispose();
        if (file != null)
            file.delete();
        String fileName = JOptionPane
                .showInputDialog("Please input the name of you file: ");
        if (fileName != null) {
            if (fileName.trim().equals("")) {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame(
                        "JOptionPane showMessageDialog example");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,
                        "File Name must have some value", "Warning Message",
                        JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            } else {

                Connection conn = DBConnectionHandler.getConnection();
                PreparedStatement pstmt;
                try {
                    pstmt = conn
                            .prepareStatement("insert into FILEDATA(PR_KEY, FILENAME, FILEDATA) values (seq_file.nextval,?, EMPTY_BLOB())");
                    pstmt.setString(1, fileName + ".docx");
                    pstmt.executeUpdate();
                } catch (SQLException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    static void fileOpen() {
        List<String> FileName = new ArrayList<String>();
        try {
            Connection conn = DBConnectionHandler.getConnection();
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            ResultSet rset = stmt.executeQuery("select FILENAME from FILEDATA");
            while (rset.next())
                FileName.add(rset.getString(1));
            System.out.println("List Size "+FileName.size());
            if (clientSite != null)
                clientSite.dispose();
            shell.setVisible(false);
            if (file != null)
                file.delete();
            SWTMenuExample swtClass = new SWTMenuExample();
            NewJFrame form = new NewJFrame(FileName, clientSite, shell, frame,
                    swtClass);
            form.setVisible(true);
            form.setSize(400, 400);

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        /*
         * FileDialog dialog = new FileDialog(shell, SWT.OPEN);
         * dialog.setFilterExtensions(new String[] { "*.docx" }); String
         * fileName = dialog.open(); if (fileName != null) { if (clientSite !=
         * null) clientSite.dispose(); file = new File(fileName); clientSite =
         * new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE, "Word.Document", file);
         * clientSite.addKeyListener(keyListener);
         * clientSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE); }
         */
    }

    void fileOpenFromDrive(File happyFile) {
        file = happyFile;
        display.asyncExec(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                shell.setVisible(true);
                if (clientSite != null)
                    clientSite.dispose();

                clientSite = new OleClientSite(frame, SWT.NONE,
                        "Word.Document", file);
                clientSite.addKeyListener(keyListener);
                clientSite.doVerb(OLE.OLEIVERB_INPLACEACTIVATE);

                shell.addListener(SWT.Close, new Listener() {
                    public void handleEvent(Event event) {
                        if (file != null)
                            file.delete(); 
                        shell.dispose();
                    }
                });
            }
        });

    }

    static void fileSave() {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            Connection conn = DBConnectionHandler.getConnection();

            PreparedStatement pstmt = conn
                    .prepareStatement("update FILEDATA  set FILEDATA = ?  where FILENAME = ?");
            pstmt.setBinaryStream(1, fis, (int) file.length());
            pstmt.setString(2, file.getName());
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

It will open docx as like in the following picture :

[image]

Comment: I could not get it to work, do you use some dependency for MS word?
What is this part of code? 
`NewJFrame form = new NewJFrame(FileName, clientSite, shell, frame,
                    swtClass);`

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, this sounds a lot like an XY problem—meaning, you have already decided that the best solution is using Microsoft Word, so you are asking how to embed Microsoft Word instead of asking about your actual goal, which appears to be incorporating formatted text in a user interface.

A good way to do this is with a JEditorPane containing HTML content:

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JEditorPane;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;

public class HtmlPane {
    static void show() {
        JEditorPane content = new JEditorPane("text/html",
            "<p>" +
            "The process of finger enrollment is now to be done in database." +
            " Previously it was done in file template." +
            " There are several reasons behind this:" +
            "<ol>" +
            "<li>" +
            "Time:<br>" +
            "--------" +
            "<p>" +
            "The process of verification in file template based method takes" +
            " 6.9 s on average.  On the other hand, in database based method," +
            " it takes only 3.5 s." +
            "<p>" +
            "The code for determining time is as follows:" +
            "<blockquote>" +
            "<pre>" +
            "Dim StartTime, Elapsed Time\n" +
            "StartTime = Timer\n" +
            "ElapsedTime = Timer.CheckTime\n" +
            "</pre>" +
            "</blockquote>" +
            "</ol>");

        content.setEditable(false);

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("finger");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new JScrollPane(content));

        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> show());
    }
}
```

(Note:  The Swing HTML renderer only supports HTML 3.2.)

If you aren’t familiar with HTML, I advise you to learn it.  Basic HTML is *very* easy to write.  Plus, you need to know basic HTML to be an effective Java programmer, because professional development requires writing javadoc, and all javadoc is in HTML.

Comment: I want to open a word document with microsoft word which is limited to JForm .

Answer (score -1):

Actaully, you can't show any not-your-project-frames in your java gui application, it is actaully unreal - you can only show java frames in JInternalFrame